# Symfony variable not exist error message

Tags: php, symfony

I am new to Symfony framework. I am having some difficulties in pulling data from database. Here is my controller class:

```
class CrisisCtrl extends Controller{
public function listAction(Request $request)
{
    $locations = $this->getDoctrine()->getRepository('AppBundle:Crisis')->findAll();
    return $this->render(':index.html.twig', array(
        'locations' => $locations
    ));
}
}
```

I followed an online tutorial to type all these out manually. When I typed `$this->`, I tried to find `getDoctrine()` from the suggestion list, however, I got nothing to select, therefore I typed them out manually and I not sure if this will cause any problem or not because apparently my code have some errors for now.

Inside my index.html.twig, I got these:

```
{% extends 'base.html.twig' %}

{% block page_content %}
// all the HTML
{% endblock %}
{% block custom_javascripts %}
<!-- Custom Theme Scripts -->
<script src="...//removed code"
        async defer></script>

<script>
{% for location in locations %}
    var map;
    function initMap() {
        var myLatLng = {lat: '{{ location.latitude }}', lng: '{{ location.latitude }}' };
        map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), {
            center: myLatLng,
            zoom: 10
        });

        var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
           position: myLatLng,
           map: map,
           title: 'Hello World!'
       });
   }
{% endfor %}
</script>

{% endblock %}
```

However, I am getting error message saying the `variable 'locations' does not exist` and the error is highlighted at the for loop in twig. I have been researching on other ways to fetch data from database and all of them are doing the same way.

I have no idea why is it so. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

**UPDATED**

In my DefaultController class, I have these:

```
class DefaultController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * @Template("AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
     * @Route("/", name="homepage")
     */
    public function indexAction(Request $request)
    {
        return array();
    }
}
```

The problem now is that the action is not calling the CrisisCtrl class. It is now executing the function above. I am not allowed to touch this function because if I changed it, other functions will be malfunctioned.

So in my CrisisCtrl class, before the listAction, I added these:

```
 /**
 * @Template("AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
```

My file  structure as such:

[image]

and my JavaScript is nested inside the index.html.twig. So I wonder how do I actually specify the route?

Comment: If you do a `dump($locations)` in the controller (right before the `return`) do you get any results? Also, which version of Symfony are you using?

Comment: what's the exact line that causes the error? @tftd is right, try checking what's in $locations - var_dump($locations) or at least do count($locations).

Comment: I am using symphony 3.2.6. How do I check the dump? Sorry I am new to Symfony and still trying to familiarize with it :) There is a toolbar-like menu at the bottom of the page and its showing one error which is the error I mentioned above

Comment: just do var_dump($locations); die();

Comment: Alright but then it is showing the same error page as previously. Where am I supposed to trace it?

Comment: are you sure you're in the right route? how do you route that action?

Comment: @SergeiKutanov I just add in that line and refresh the page. I have uploaded the image of my toolbar. I don't see any dump there. Am I in the right path?

Comment: Do a `\Doctrine\Common\Util\Debug::dump($location);exit;` this will let you know if you are getting any data

Comment: @lbu The whole page after adding the line just look like that. Where can I actually see if there is any data? Netbean console or there is any specific extra things that I need to install in order to see it?

Comment: @Fyndy - how do you route the action to url?

Comment: Seeing the `debug bar`, it's saying that it's accessing the `@homepage` route. Is that route pointing to the `CrisisCtrl` class? If not, then you're trying to access the wrong URL (or the routing is wrong), but the URL which you're accessing is using the `twig template` you modified. Therefore, it's not finding the `$locations` variable, because the loaded controller is not setting it.  BTW, try to use the convention - controller classes are named `MyNameController`.

Comment: for test purpose, remove  `{% block custom_javascripts %}...{% endblock %}`. Dump location here `{% block page_content %}
{{ dump(locations) }}
{% endblock %}`. What do you get ?

Comment: @tftd How do I specify the route? I have updated the question already

Comment: You can't have two routes with the same name and path. Change the route of your `CrisisController` to `@Route("/new/path", name="crisis_index")` and it will load the `CrisisController`. Afterwards, things should be working as far as I could see from your code.

Comment: @Fyndy you **REALLY** need to read the docs. The questions and problems you're having now are due to ignorance. Furthermore, you can't have 2 routes pointing to the same url (not to mention they're having the same name!). [Read the docs](http://symfony.com/doc/current/index.html).

Answer (score 0):

from symfony controller you should use

```
$this->getDoctrine()->getManager()->getRepository()
```

Comment: Nope it does not work. But is it normal because I did not see the getDoctrine() from suggestion list after typed the ->. I watched a video tutorial, and those things appeared after they typed the ->

Comment: what controller class do you extend? that's the one you should use Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller;

Comment: Yeah I am using that one.

Comment: You can directly call the `getRepository()` method via `$this->getDoctrine()->getRepository()`. That shouldn't be the problem - at least not in the newer versions (>=3.1). In older version you had to call the manager before that :)

Comment: @tftd But the getDoctrine() is not in the suggestion list. Could that be a problem? Because right now the error is unable to find the 'locations' and I am thinking if it is because of the controller part.

Comment: If the controller is extending `Symfony\Bundle\FrameworkBundle\Controller\Controller` (as @SergeiKutanov mentioned) you should be able to access doctrine and the repository without any problems and it should be showing in the suggestion list. However, if the IDE is not suggesting it - you probably need to refresh/invalidate the cache of the IDE.

Comment: @tftd Hmm do you have any idea why the variable does not exist?

Answer (score 0):

Change

```
class CrisisCtrl extends Controller{
```

To

```
class CrisisController extends Controller{
```

You can not use same route name in two controller. So, remove

```
/**
 * @Template("AppBundle:Default:index.html.twig")
 * @Route("/", name="homepage")
 */
```

From Default controller.